# Ios Streaming to Wowza Media Server

Tags: ios, streaming, wowza

I am developing an iOS application to stream video to wowza media server. I used MediaCommuncation Library for iOS and `RTSPStreamPublisher`. I am unable to connect to server with following issue:

```
RTMPStreamPublisher[527:90315] RTMPClient -> eventFailed: code = -7, description = fault code = -1 < Input or/and Output Stream is not opened
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to check your wowwza Source security setting. By default RTMP Source Authentication is turned on and this RTSPStreamPublisher does not take any username and password from you so wowza rejects connection.

try to go to wows stream engine-> live -> source Authentication -> open RTMP Protocol... and then restart your server....

After that try to run your RTSPStreamPublisher... Enjoy.. :-)